# Sorting/Ordering Poll Plugin?

Tags: plugins, poll

I want to create a poll in which the user is presented with a short list of items which they are then to sort in an order they choose related to the question.

After looking around for a while, I found a few good poll plugins for WordPress, but they were all of the simple radio-button/check-box variety; none of them supported this type.

Writing my own simple form is simple enough, but then I have to accommodate the data storage somehow. It would be better if I could find some sort of plugin.

Comment: So what is your question? Plugin recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) now, it is not clear if you want to know how to solve that with own code. Please improve the question.

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation, I am trying to find out if *any exist at all*.

Comment: @synetech, For the record/posterity, I ended up finding some existing DHTML examples that could do this, so I picked the [best one](http://tool-man.org/ToolManDHTML/sorting.html), stripped it down, wrapped it in an HTML form using JS to heavily modify and extend it and maximize usability and accessibility, and added a PHP backend. I “lurve” the end result! `◉‿◉`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with toscho. Regardless that this is off topic by asking for plugin recommendations, I think you just need to adjust how you are making the poll, rather than what plugin you are using or how you code it. I would split the poll up into mini polls for each answer position. [Example](http://www.linkdesigns.net/images/poll.png). Sorry about the link...new here, couldn't post an image.

I created this using the poll add-on for Gravity forms which I would highly recommend, but I believe you could achieve this with any kind of poll plugin that supports a drop down selection option

Comment: Blech! Thanks for the suggestion, but doing it that way is horrendous and not very user-friendly. I’d rather implement a JavaScript drag-and-drop form myself.